# Changing the arrow heads in pgfplots axis lines

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

Consider the following:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz,pgfplots}

\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\tikzset{>={Latex[round]}}
\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[inner axis line style={>={Latex[round]},very thick,red},
                 axis lines=center]
       \addplot [->,>={Latex[round]}] coordinates {( 0,0)(1,1)};
    \end{axis}
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Notice that the "very thick" and "red" style options are changed but the >={Latex[round]} one isn't. Is there another option just for arrow heads in axis lines ? I couldn't find any in the doc.

[image]

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use

```
axis line style={-Latex[round]}
```

or (`x axis line style`, for example).

[image]

The code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}

\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[inner axis line style={very thick,red},
                 axis lines=center,axis line style={-Latex[round]}]
       \addplot [->,>={}] coordinates {( 0,0)(1,1)};
    \end{axis}
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I was `20sec` too slow! Nice work Gonzalo. :-)

Comment: Thanks, what's the difference between the >=Latex[] form that works in a \draw command and the -Latex[] one?

Comment: @wilk The latter uses the `<start arrow specification>-<end arrow specification>` syntax.

Comment: @wilk the difference is that `>=Latex` set the default arrow as `Latex`. So if we use later `->` this will be equivalent to `-Latex`, but `>=Latex` will have no effect on `-stealth`. So if one style install `-stealth`, to overwrite it you have to set `-Letex` or `>=Latex,->` after it.

Answer (score 8):

Note that `axis lines=center` installs the following style

```
/pgfplots/every non boxed x axis/.style={%
  xtick align=center,
  enlarge x limits=false,
  x axis line style={-stealth}
},
```

So the order of the options is crucial. You have to change the `axis lines` firstly and the `inner axis line style` (or `axis line style`) secondly.

Additionally, the arrow tip is set to `stealth` explicitly. Therefore, it has no effect if the default arrow tip `>` is redefined by `inner axis line style`. You have to use `-Latex[round]` instead.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[
    axis lines=center,
    inner axis line style={-Latex[round],very thick,red}
  ]
     \addplot[] coordinates {( 0,0)(1,1)};
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: (+1) Good point for the order. But not only the order is crucial : as the arrow is set by `-stealth` and not by `->,>=stealth`, it can't be overwritten with `>={Latex[round]}`, we have to use `-{Latex[round]}`.

Comment: @Kpym Thanks for the hint. I have added this in my answer.

Comment: @esdd How can one achieve this result when rather using `axis lines=left`?

Comment: @tush With `axis lines=left` you have to change  `outer axis line style`: 
`outer axis line style={-Latex[round],very thick,red}`